Solve the equation: $x^2-yz = a^2$, $y^2-zx = b^2$, $z^2-xy = c^2$, $x + y + z = 0$.

Solve the equation: $x^2-yz = a^2$, $y^2-zx = b^2$, $z^2-xy = c^2$, $x + y + z = 0$.

Summing the first 3, getting $\sum{xy} = \frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{-3}$
Also, we've $\sum{x^3} = 3xyz$.
But still not getting how to use these to solve it.

Please edit your posted question, striving to make it impossible for anyone to be confused about your analysis.  Please do not respond with a comment.  For example, I am confused about the following:  $$ $$Summing the first 3, getting $\sum{xy} = \frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{-3}$ $$ $$
Also, we've $\sum{x^3} = 3xyz$. $$ $$

Re my last comment, also, please edit your posted question, carefully showing all of the analysis that led to your interim conclusions, line by line.  Again, please do not respond with a comment.

@user2661923 I think that those are reasonable conclusions given the initial statements. I'm not sure how much "substantiate your work" is required/appreciated, though you could ask for further clarification.

@CalvinLin I don't understand what those statements mean.

@user2661923 Are you saying that you don't understand what $\sum$ is? That's the summation notation, and in this case, we have  $ \sum xy = xy+yz+zx,  \sum x^3 = x^3 + y3 + z^3$. $\quad$ If not, please clarify what you are confused by.

Quick question: are $x,y,z$ real or can they be complex? A nice question - I've seen a few similar on old (pre 1940s) university entrance exams here in Australia.

@CalvinLin No, that part I understood.  What I did not immediately get was how the OP arrived at his conclusion.  I assumed that he was mis-stating something.  Then, after I saw your comment, I re-read the problem title.  Now, I see what's going on, and I agree with you that the conclusions are reasonable.  However, the OP should have included the title-constraint directly in the posted question and should have provided the analytical step that led to the conclusion.  You don't want the MathSE reviewer to have to work to confirm the OP's analysis: the analysis should be handed to the reviewer

@user2661923 the "analysis" is relative. To some people (and probably the OP), this step was fairly obvious

Hint: Substitute $z = -(x+y)$ into the first 2 equations to show that $a^2 = b^2 = c^2$.
Hence, $ x = y = z$, per the observations made in your post from a few months back.
